# Laravel 5 Eloquent ORM multi relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

I'm totally new in Laravel, and I'm trying to create relations between models. My tables are:

```
patch
    id
    title

area
    id
    location

area_patch
    id
    patch_id
    area_id

user_area_patch
    id
    area_patch_id
    plant_id
    plant_date
```

User model, "patchs" function should execute something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.title, up.plant_id, up.plant_date
FROM
    rsst_farming_patch p
JOIN rsst_farming_area_patch pp, 
    rsst_farming_user_patch up ON pp.id = up.area_patch_id AND p.id = pp.patch_id WHERE up.user_id = 1
```

my models:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function patchs() {
        //return user patchs
    }
}
class Patch extends Model {
     public function area() {
         //return area that this patch belongs to
     }
}
class Area extends Model {
    public function patchs() {
         //return available patchs
    }
}
```

can some one make an example of this? I would like to study it. I was messing around with User model, belongsToMany and hasManyThrough, but no luck.

Comment: Laravel 5 now uses namespace in the relationship declaration, did you forget them ?
And, can you explain more explicitly (?) what are you trying to do and how !

Answer (score 1):

You may need to modify your table structure slightly to make this happen.

I see in your`user_area_patch` table you are trying to link the user, area, and patches together. That's not typically how I've done it in laravel. Normally you use a [pivot table](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) to link two items together. So let me suggest something like this:

Does a patch belong to a single user? If so you should add a user_id to the patch table.

```
patch
    id
    user_id
    area_id
    title
```

Can an a Patch be in multiple areas? I kind of doubt it, so I'd add an `area_id` as well.

```
class User extends Model {
    public function patchs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App/Patch', 'user_id');
    }
}
class Patch extends Model {
    public function area() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Area', 'area_id');
    }
}
class Area extends Model {
    public function patchs() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Patch', 'patch_id');
    } 
}
```

Then you can start referencing your patchs like:

`$patchs = User::find(1)->patchs()`

or the area that a patch belongs to by

`Patch::find(1)->area()`

and all the patchs in an area by

`Area::find(1)->patchs()`

Does this help?